# What does $C^0$ stand for?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

I've come across the symbol $C^0$ in studying functional analysis. I don't know what $C^0$ means in the context below.

---

Define $\mathscr C^\alpha$ for $\alpha >0$ as
$$\mathscr C^\alpha :=\{ f :\mathbb R\to \mathbb C \mid \exists M>0 \ ; \ |f(x)-f(y)|\leqq M|x-y|^\alpha \ \mathrm{for \ all} \ x,y \in \mathbb R \}$$
If $f \in \mathscr C^\alpha,$ $f$ is called uniformly $\alpha$-Holder continuous function.

Let $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ be a periodic function.
Then, prove that $f \in \mathscr C^\alpha \Longrightarrow f\in C^0$.

(Perhaps the periodicity of $f$ isn't necessary.)

---

I searched and investigated what $C^0$ means but I couldn't find.

Does anybody know what this is ?

Comment: Certainly $C^0$ should have been defined before this point.  If it wasn't, you have a very bad textbook.  My guess?  $C^0$ is the set of continuous functions.

Comment: It is likely that periodicity is not required : $\mathscr C^\alpha$ alone should imply $C^0$ (usually the set of real/complex-valued continuous functions that are continuous on $\mathbb R$) using an $\epsilon-\delta$ argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made it a post because I am not allowed to comment yet. Usually in the textbook of functional analysis and PDEs we use the following definition: Let $\Omega$ be open subset of $\mathbb{R}$, then

$$C^0 (\overline{\Omega}, \mathbb{R})= \{ f: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}, f \text{ is continuous}\}$$
equipped with the norm

$$\| f\|_{c^0_b} = \sup_{x \in \Omega} | f(x)|.$$

So $C^0$ is just the continuous functions. See this link for the proof: [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2750127/hölder-continuous-functions-are-uniformly-continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2750127/h%C3%B6lder-continuous-functions-are-uniformly-continuous).

Comment: The "allowed to comment" issue is not an issue, if you feel that your text answers the question. Welcome to Math Stack.

Comment: @311411 Thank you so much.